# How can I turn off source echo in Rstudio

Tags: r

Can I prevent R from echoing the source code in the console in RStudio?

I have tried options(echo=F) and options(verbose=F)

Comment: Are you talking about when you click on "Run" or `ctrl+Enter`?

Comment: I'd like to be able to do it either one of those two ways.

Comment: The closest thing I know of is that you can removed the output (printed, not the actual objects) or clear the console by using `Ctrl + L`.

Comment: Take a look in this https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts

Comment: Rstudio is for running code interactively. If you want it to run in batch, use the command line.

Comment: It would be great to have this option, as we have it inside knitr chunks

Answer (score 6):

Looks like pressing `Ctrl+Shift+S` which sources the current document without echo might fit your case.

Answer (score 1):

In R Studio, you can run the current script with the below code (check out ?source for more information on other arguments that might be helpful for other reasons)

```
source('~/.active-rstudio-document', print.eval = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question but thought this could be helpful.

You can toggle the RStudio echo on/off using the "Source" button options (top right of source code window). As previously mention <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> - source without echo or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> - source with echo.